# What is the best way to handle multiple (potentially null) navigation properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 classes

```
    public class ActivityLog
    {
          //  The activity log affects an employee
          public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
          public Employee Employee { get; set; }

          //  The activity log affects a department
          public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
          public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

In this example there are two different object types that could be displayed on the view, but in reality there are much more types that differ and for which it doesn't seem sensible to move it to its own inheritance model.

I would like to be able to do the below:

```
    public class ActivityLog<T>
    {
        //  The activity log affects an unknown type
        public T ConcernedObjectID { get; set; }
        public T ConcernedObject { get; set; } 
    }
```

Right now we have a lot of null checks in our view (if employee is null then use department).

Is this something that entity framework can help with somehow, or would it be best to implement a code only solution (e.g. Interfaces)?

Comment: What would be a possible query that you want to optimize?

Comment: This is quite a broad topic, there are many answers here. The main question, I think, is whether a given `ActivityLog` object will **always** refer to the same object, or can the same `ActivityLog` object be used for both departments and employees? I suspect it's the former (one activity log always handles the same object), which suggests implementing a shared interface between all needed classes (person, department, ...) which helps you to generalize the `ActivityLog` code.

Comment: _"but in reality there are much more types that differ and for which it doesn't seem sensible to move it to its own inheritance model"_ Can you elaborate why you think this is correct? I would argue the opposite. The **more** classes there are, the **higher** the need for a generalized approach (either through inheritance or interface implementation), as the benefit of doing so drastically increases with each extra class that you would otherwise have to manually code every time.

Comment: Thank you, we implemented an inheritance model for the ActivityLog and ended up having one table generated by entity framework per type of activity log.

Comment: I think my concern was that it creates one table for each type, but as the answer said it was trying to do too much, so this simplifies things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a design problem here. The ActivityLog class tries to do too much. Its both an entry in the log for an employee and for a department. Which are completely different things. The only thing they have in common is that they can be put into an activity log.

I would either use a common interface or an abstract base class. You can then use the asp.net equivalent of data templates to visualize the data.

So something like this:

```
public abstract class ActivityLogEntry
{
   int Id { get; }
}

public EmployeeActivityLogEntry : ActivityLogEntry
{
    Employee Employee {get;}
}

public DepartmentActivityLogEntry : ActivityLogEntry
{
    Department Department {get;}
}
```

Another thing that can help you with null checks is to make it explicit that something can be null. I use the [Optional](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Optional/) NuGet package for that. This gives you something like this

```
Option<Employee> Employee {get; }

public string ToString()
{
    return this.Employee.Match(e => e.Name, () => "");
}
```

In this case you cannot directly access the Employee that is captured in the Option. Instead you have to provide a `Func` for what to do when there is an Employee (its not null) and for when there isn't. There are a lot more helper functions in the optional library. It makes it a lot clearer that you need to handle both cases. You can no longer be surprised by something begin null.

(Of course you should not use `Option<T>` for everything. Only use it on properties that can sometimes be null. Not on properties that should never be null, or you start hiding bugs from yourself).

Comment: Thanks, we ended up using your advice to implement an inheritance model and simply having one different table for each activity log generated by entity framework.